# Doubt on Cauchy Stress tensor: a partial derivative of metric tensor?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, elasticity, continuum-mechanics

In the reference $[1]$ the author presented a definition of Stress tensor:

> $$ \sigma = 2 \rho \frac{\partial e}{\partial g} \tag{1}$$

In a local chart we have:

> $$ \sigma_{ab} = 2 \rho \frac{\partial e}{\partial g_{ab}} \tag{2}$$

So, $\rho$ is the mass density, $e$ the energy density and $g$ the metric tensor.

**My question is: what suppose to mean the "metric derivative" $\partial/ \partial g$?**

$$* * *$$

$[1]$ MARSDEN.J, HUGHES.T.J.R; *Mathematical Foundations of Elasticity*. page 165. Thm 4.13.

Comment: Do you understand the equation (2) and **just** the notation in equation (1) confuses you? Or both equations confuse you?

Comment: @RenatoRenatoRenato in fact I do not understand the derivative $\partial/ \partial g_{ab}$. Could be something in the context of tensor densities and derivative of metric determinant?